# remove image tag from strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove `<img>` tags from my DB call that is returning string.

The string example is like the following

```
dummy textdummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text
<img src='text.jpg'/>
dummy textdummy text 
<img src='text1.jpg'/>dummy textdummy text dummy textdummy text 
dummy textdummy text 
<img src='text3.jpg'/>
```

The position of the `image tag` and `image src` could be vary but the main purpose is to remove `<img>` tag.

`replace` won't work in my case

Are there any ways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Jay, what a great link. I thought it was a joke, and then I read that and was like. Wow, what a reasonable, patient way to approach this problem.

Comment: "`replace` won't work in my case" - why not?

Comment: You should wrap your string in jquery object then use remove() method on all image tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just want to remove the html tags and keep the text on the client side?  Why not just turn it into a jQuery object and use the .text() method

```
$(yourstring).text();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DDjFz/

Unless there are other tags you want to keep then I'll post another answer

EDIT:

If you just want to remove image elements.. you can use the filter function

```
var newString = $(x).filter(function() {
     return this.tagName != 'IMG';
}).text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/47bcJ/

Technically `$(x).filter(':not(img)').text()` should work but not sure why it's not

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning data from your database using PHP, have you considered [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)? It removes HTML tags (and PHP, too!)

Or are you looking for a JavaScript solution? Try [this](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/). There's lots of other PHP functions ported to JavaScript over there, too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that removed specific `img` elements: http://jsfiddle.net/DDjFz/2/

```
<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'/>
<ul>
  <li>dummy textdummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150'/></li>
  <li>dummy textdummy text <img src='http://placekitten.com/200/300'/></li>
  <li>dummy textdummy text dummy textdummy text dummy textdummy text <img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'/></li>
</ul>
```

Using this script:

```
$('li > img').remove();
```

If you wanted to remove all of them you could just use:

```
$('img').remove();
```

Comment: It would be the perfect opportunity to share [SheenHolders.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/the-top-8-placeholders-for-web-designers/) but tragically this site appears to be down

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").each(function(){
        var i = $(this).attr("src");
        $(".display").append('<p>' + i + '</p>'); 
    });
});
```

With the append you can see the results in your html page.